# Android start/stop service if USB device is plugged in/removed without Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, usb

I am trying to start a Service on Android as soon as a certain USB device is plugged in. I have already found [this example](https://github.com/follower/android-background-service-usb-accessory), which launches an (invisible) activity with an intent-filter, which on the other hand launches the service.

However, this seems to me a little bit hackery and I am trying to do the same with a `BroadcastReceiver` with the following code:

```
public class UsbMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public UsbMessageReceiver() {
        Log.d("UsbMessageReceiver", "Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
        // an Intent broadcast.
        Log.d("UsbMessageReceiver", "onReceive");
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

And the manifest:

```
<receiver
  android:name=".UsbMessageReceiver"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true" >
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
  </intent-filter>

  <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />

</receiver>
```

Edit: If forgot to mention that this approach does not work. I don't get the log message and the Error is not thrown. Is this possible without invoking an Activity?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but I think you must use some blogging site for posting suggestions and leave StackOverflow for those who seek answer to their problems.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that my approach does not work. Hence the question: What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using bellow code launch the service in on recieve method

context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));

Comment: The problem is not the service-launching part, the problem is that the onReceive method is not called. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: add the  tag in manifest   <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />